# Syntax for a connection string to Mongo database using a "Trusted Connection"

Tags: mongodb, iis, connection-string

I have question about how I would go about formatting Mongo database connection strings so that they aren't passing plain text credentials. I've got an ASP.NET website running in IIS and we have several connection strings for both SQL and Mongo databases.  In order to get around having plain text credentials, we have been encrypting the connection string file... which I am trying to do away with.  For the SQL connections, this is easy enough to do using a trusted connection syntax.  However, I'm at a loss for how to do this with the Mongo connections. We have an enterprise version of Mongo running and I need to find out how I can use something akin to a trusted connection for Mongo database connection strings.  Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You might not be able to get rid of all the credentials in your connection string, but at least lose the password. Might be worth it?

Take a look: http://sitecorelearningcurve.blogspot.com/2015/07/using-kerberos-to-authenticate-sitecore.html

P.S. If you have found the solution already, you are more than welcome to post it here as your own answer!! :)